# How to shutdown my laptop automatically if I'm away for 30 minutes

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, dell-inspiron

I'm using a Dell Inspiron N5110 running Windows 7. Please tell me how to shutdown my laptop automatically if I'm away from it for 30 minutes or more.

Comment: Do you really want to shut down, or simply sleep or hibernate?  (Or simply lock?)  If you shut down you lose any work you were in the middle of.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks : if i m downloading something, will it be download after hibernate or sleep

Comment: Unclear:  Do you mean, will a download that completes before sleep/hibernate be available after "reawakening"?  If so, yes.  But sleeping/hibernating in the middle of a download will probably (but not certainly) cause the download to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with task scheudler and a bat file

Create a bat file by: open notepad, and type the string

`shutdown.exe /s /t 00`

Save this file to your My Documents directory and name it Shutdown.bat (note the `.bat` extension and not `.txt`).

Then, open Task Scheulder (type `task s` from start menu)

Create a new task (not basic)

Give it a name

On idle

In Conditions tab, select `start the task only if the computer is idle for 30 minutes`

Now, in Actions tab, click New start a program and brose for your .bat file.

Click OK until it's saved!

All done!

As an aside, just be careful in regards that you may lose unsaved work; Also, this *may* not be desirable if a background update is running or a download etc

Comment: You should go add this to the tagged dupe. :)

Comment: @techie007, are you able to move this for me, or should I just copy and paste it over?

Comment: I can't move it. IMO I'd say yeah, just C&P -- or perhaps flag it to get a mod involved? :)